# Specifying filters for ELMAH in web.config

Tags: elmah

I am interested in specifying filters for ELMAH, when any one of these 2 exceptions occurs in my asp.net app.

1. Exception message contains 'This is an invalid webresource request'
2. Exception Message contains 'A potentially dangerous... value...'

I used the following in my web.config, but it only filters invalid websresource request if its placed as the first filter, but if its placed as second filter then it doesn't apply. The config file 'errorfilter' element is as given below. How can I specify both these conditions in web config, and do I need to use BaseException.Message or Exception.Message?

```
    <errorFilter>
    <test>
     <or>
       <and>
        <regex binding="Exception.Message" pattern="(?ix: \b potentially \b.+?\b  
            dangerous \b.+?\b value \b.+?\b detected \b.+?\b client \b )" />
      </and>  
    </or>
    <or>
      <and>
          <equal binding="BaseException.Message" value="This is an invalid webresource
          request." type="String" />
      </and>
    </or>
    </test>   
    </errorFilter>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `test` element can have only one child element. Since you have two `or` conditions under it, only the first one is ever being applied. The correct way to *or* your two conditions would be to group them under a single `or` element, under `test`, like this:

```
<errorFilter>
  <test>
    <or>
        <regex binding="Exception.Message" 
               pattern="(?ix: \b potentially \b.+?\b  
                        dangerous \b.+?\b value \b.+?\b 
                        detected \b.+?\b client \b )" />
        <equal binding="BaseException.Message" 
               value="This is an invalid webresource request." 
               type="String" />
    </or>
  </test>
</errorFilter>
```